# Failure connecting to S/4 Hana via Cloud SDK

Tags: s4sdk

I'm following the OData tutorial at https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/comment-page-1/ and I'm getting an error when I try to retrieve business partners using `DefaultBusinessPartnerService`.

The relevant piece of code is:

```
        DefaultBusinessPartnerService businessPartnerService = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();
        System.err.println("criated default business partner");

        List<BusinessPartner> partners = businessPartnerService
                .getAllBusinessPartner()
                .select(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER,
                        BusinessPartner.LAST_NAME,
                        BusinessPartner.FIRST_NAME)
                //.filter(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER_CATEGORY.eq(CATEGORY_VENDOR))
                .orderBy(BusinessPartner.LAST_NAME, Order.ASC)
                .execute(new ErpEndpoint(new ErpConfigContext()));

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(partners));
```

My `ErpQueryEndpoint` configuration is as follows:

```
#Mon May 14 15:27:09 BRT 2018
URL=https\://host\:port
Name=ErpQueryEndpoint
TrustAll=TRUE
Type=HTTP
Password=Password
Authentication=BasicAuthentication
User=Username
```

Where `host`, `port`, `Username` and `Password` have been replaced by the correct values.

When I query `http://localhost:8080/s4integration-application/businesspartners` I get the following error:

```
The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 403.
No service found for namespace , name API_BUSINESS_PARTNER, version 0001
Full error message: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "/IWFND/MED/170",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "No service found for namespace , name API_BUSINESS_PARTNER, version 0001"
    },
    "innererror": {
      "application": {
        "component_id": "",
        "service_namespace": "/SAP/",
        "service_id": "API_BUSINESS_PARTNER",
        "service_version": "0001"
      },
      "transactionid": "C83CB3D2A1420000E005AF97B0836AD5",
      "timestamp": "20180514182746.3576100",
      "Error_Resolution": {
        "SAP_Transaction": "Run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system (System Alias ) and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details",
        "SAP_Note": "See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)"
      },
      "errordetails": []
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that the endpoint is not configured on the SAP system (it's an S/4 Hana system). I'm not sure if I have to add something else to the `URL` besides the host and port or if there is some other configuration that has to be done on the SAP system.

Comment: Just for clarification before we consider an answer: Is your system an S/4HANA on-prem or cloud system that you are trying to connect. Which version of S/4HANA is this system? Thank you.

Comment: On System status I see `HDB 1.00.112.04.1467296086` and `S4CORE` release 101. Not sure if you need more info. It's on-prem.

Comment: S4CORE release 101 sp 0000

Comment: Looks as if the OData service API_BUSINESS_PARTNER is not exposed from your SAP S/4HANA system. In order to check that, open transaction /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE and see if this API is included in the table under Service Catalog.

Comment: I can't even see it listed. I have a bunch of `ZC_...` services, such as `ZC_CUSTOMER_OP_SRV`, but can't find any `API_BUSINESS_PARTNER`. Is there a way to enable the services needed by the cloud SDK? What's weird is that I can access https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/C_PURCHASEORDER_FS_SRV/C_PurchaseOrderFs?$top=10 from my browser. It seems the services names expected by the Cloud SDK are not there.

Comment: Instructions for activating OData APIs from the SAP S/4HANA backend can be found here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/cdc25c83b63e482586b31b8acd49cf2f/1610%20003/en-US/4c288b58841a3132e10000000a441470.html

Just ignore the notion of the Fiori app.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for activating OData APIs from the SAP S/4HANA backend can be found here: help.sap.com/viewer/cdc25c83b63e482586b31b8acd49cf2f/1610%20003/… Just ignore the notion of the Fiori app.